# Saving variables to php file

Tags: php

Im stuck at this one, the code is working properly but will not pass/save variables to 'sample.php' file newely created.

```
<?php

$id = 3;
$name = "John Smith";

$myfile = fopen("sample.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "
  <?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
  // Set session variables
  $_SESSION[\"user\"] = $id;            // integer variable
  $_SESSION[\"name\"] = \"$name\";  // string variable
  header('Location: home/start.php');
  ?>
";

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: you have double quotes inside that string so it won't work

Comment: what are trying todo here. Please tell objective.

Comment: actually now nothing happens, is it brackets issue?

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to interpolate the variables correctly

```
$txt = '
  <?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
  // Set session variables
  $_SESSION["user"] = '.$id.';     
  $_SESSION["name"] = "'.$name.'";  
  header("Location: home/start.php");
?>';
```

Single quotes make sure your session variables do not get interpolated in your string and only `$id` and `$name` do

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/488085)**

**Output**

```
 <?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
  // Set session variables
  $_SESSION["user"] = 2;     
  $_SESSION["name"] = "John";  
  header("Location: home/start.php");
?>
```

Comment: ....and i have a new best friend this Christmas....cheers fella!! :D

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just escape the $ on the session variables.

```
$str = "\$_SESSION['foo']";
```

Otherwise Php will try and substitute them within the string.

Answer (score 0):

try this, use single quote to round the variable

```
 $id = 3;
$name = "John Smith";

$myfile = fopen("sample.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = '
  <?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
  // Set session variables
  $_SESSION["user"] = '. $id . ';  // integer variable   
  $_SESSION["name"] = "'. $name . '";  // string variable
  header(\'Location: home/start.php\');
?>';

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: cant get it working..

Comment: if i remove <?php and  ?> it outputs correct, but on the other hand the file will not have php opening and closing brackets..

Answer (score -1):

Solved -I found out that open and close bracket in php must be parsed as variable to actually be included in the new file. Thanks for quotation help!

```
<?php

$id = 3;
$name = "John Smith";
$open = "<?php";
$close = "?>";

$myfile = fopen("sample.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = '
 '.$open.'
 // Start the session
 session_start();
 // Set session variables
 $_SESSION["user"] = '.$id.';
 $_SESSION["name"] = "'.$name.'";
 header("Location: home/start.php");
 '.$close.'
';
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Output to sample.php:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["user"] = 3;
$_SESSION["name"] = "John Smith";
header("Location: home/start.php");
?>
```

Comment: This is a very tough way to do a simple thing. You dont have to create all those extra lines and variables